# Construtor com um String e um array de String não está dando certo

Tags: java

Eu criei estas linhas de códigos num exercicio de Java ...

```
public class Pizza {
    ...
    public Pizza (String nomeDestaPizza, String[] arrayIngredientes) {
        ...
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    Pizza pizza1 = new Pizza("americana", "molho de tomate", "mussarela", "presunto", "tomate", "azeitona"); 
    ...
}
```

Na linha que criei uma instância da classe Pizza  (pizza1) está apresentado esta mensagem de erro no IDE Eclipse:

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - Line breakpoint:Principal [line: 7] - main(String[])
> - The constructor Pizza(String, String, String, String, String) is undefined.

Alguém saberia o que pode esta acontecendo e como posso resolver?

Answer (score 5):

Para poder instanciar a classe *Pizza* dessa forma declare o segundo parâmetro do construtor como [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html):

```
public class Pizza {

    public Pizza (String nomeDestaPizza, String... arrayIngredientes) {

    }
}
```

Os 3 pontos após *String*(`String...`) indica que é possível passar um número indeterminado de parâmetros do tipo String.

Eles poderão ser passados através de um *String Array* ou vários *Strings* separados por vírgula.

Qualquer que seja a opção escolhida eles serão guardados em um *Array*(neste caso `arrayIngredientes`).

Assim, a classe *Pizza* pode ser instanciada destas duas formas:

Forma 1:

```
Pizza pizza1 = new Pizza("americana", "molho de tomate", "mussarela", "presunto", "tomate", "azeitona");
```

Forma 2:

```
String[] ingredientes = {"molho de tomate", "mussarela", "presunto", "tomate", "azeitona"};
Pizza pizza1 = new Pizza("Americana", ingredientes);
```

Answer (score 4):

Você está passando os ingredientes como objetos simples não como array.
Faça dessa maneira:

```
//você cria o array de Strings
String[] ingredientes = {"molho de tomate", "mussarela", "presunto", "tomate", "azeitona"};
//e depois passa para o construtor da classe
Pizza pizza1 = new Pizza("Americana", ingredientes);
```